# What is the "Dfs" User That Has Permissions to DFS Namespace Links

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I recently ran into issues that seem to be related to this "Dfs" user (which is added automatically when you create a new namespace link.) I can't find this user in any local or domain user store, nor can I find any documentation on what it does...but apparently it needs full control of the DFS namespace links for thinks to work correctly. What is this user, and where can I find documentation on it's purpose?

Comment: "I recently ran into issues that seem to be related to this "Dfs" user (which is added automatically when you create a new namespace link.)" Added where?

Comment: Added to the link (namespace folders, although Microsoft's new nomenclature for DFS is to call them "links), under the namespace share.